# How to prevent form submission without required fields?

Tags: php, zend-framework, form-submit, required-field

I am creating forms elements like this:

```
$element = $this->CreateElement('select', 'countries');
$element->setLabel('Countries');
$element->setAttrib( 'required', true );
$element->addMultiOptions( array( ''=>'Select', '1'=>'Aus','2'=>'UK',.... ) );
```

Following code is submitting form:

```
// form
$form = new SomeForm();

// get request
$request = $this->getRequest();

// isPost
if( $request->isPost() ) {

    // isValid
    if( $form->isValid( $request->getPost() ) ) {               
         $values = $form->getValues();    
         // Save values into database here                                      
    } else {            
        $this->view->msg = "Required Fields are missing.";
    } 

} else {        
    $this->view->msg = 'Form is not submitted properly';
}
```

When I fill form properly then it save record into database successfully. But when I does not select country, it also submit form. I think I should show "Required Fields are missing." message instead of inserting values into database when required fields is missing.

What am I missing ??

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
$element->setAttrib( 'required', true );
```

doesn't really do what you think it does (it sets an HTML attribute).

You probably wanted

```
$element->setRequired(true);
```

(This is assuming you're using Zend_Form, it's not totally clear from the code you posted).